# Accuracy on test set does not increase

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression, multinomial

I am working with an image dataset and, as an opportunity for learning, coding multinomial by scratch.

I have tried multiple different batch sizes (50, 100, 200) and learning rates (.001, .05, .1, .5).

I still can't seem to get better than 1% so I am wondering if I am missing something in my code, or if this will be the best I can get with shallow learning methods. I tried logistic regression with sklearn and could get around 7% (I know, quite terrible!), and was trying to recreate the code for it in tensorflow.

Is there anyway to tell if it's actually improving? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from keras.datasets import cifar100

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()


x_train_data= np.zeros((50000, 32, 32))
for i, x in enumerate(x_train):
    x_train_data[i] = rgb2gray(x)


x_test_data= np.zeros((10000, 32, 32))
for i, x in enumerate(x_test):
    x_test_data[i] = rgb2gray(x)

#convert data to a vector
x_train_data = x_train_data.reshape((50000, -1))
x_test_data = x_test_data.reshape((10000, -1))


NUM_CLASSES = 100
X_DIM = 32
Y_DIM = 32
PIXELS_PER_SAMPLE = X_DIM*Y_DIM

#create placeholders
X =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, PIXELS_PER_SAMPLE])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_CLASSES])


#create variables
with tf.variable_scope("multi_class_logistic_model", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    W = tf.get_variable('Weight_matrix', initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (X_DIM*Y_DIM, NUM_CLASSES)))    
    W_o= tf.get_variable('bias', initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = [NUM_CLASSES]))
    Y_pred = tf.matmul(X, W)  + W_o


#convert values to probability vector using softmax
Y_pred_prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits=Y_pred)

#create loss function (cross entropy)
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.log(Y_pred_prob))

#create accuracy measurement
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_pred,1),tf.argmax(Y,1)),tf.float32))

#create optimizer
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)


BATCH_SIZE = 100
NUM_EPOCHS = 10000

#function to batch data. One hot encodes the labels
def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    '''
    Return a total of `num` random samples and labels. 
    '''
    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in labels_shuffle:
        letter = [0 for _ in range(100)]
        letter[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.append(letter)

    return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(onehot_encoded)


#one hot encode the labels test set
y_test_onehot_encoded = list()
for value in y_test.ravel():
    letter = [0 for _ in range(100)]
    letter[value] = 1
    y_test_onehot_encoded.append(letter)
y_test_onehot_encoded_array = np.array(y_test_onehot_encoded)


#run tf session
train_losses, val_losses = [], []
train_accuracies, val_accuracies = [], []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for eidx in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        epoch_acc, epoch_loss = [], []
        for bidx in range(x_train_data.shape[0]// BATCH_SIZE):
            xs, ys = next_batch(BATCH_SIZE, x_train_data, y_train.ravel())
            xs = xs.astype(np.float32)
            _, train_loss, train_acc= sess.run([opt,loss,accuracy], feed_dict={X: xs,Y: ys})
            if (bidx+1)%100 == 0: # print result every 100 batch
                print('epoch {} training batch {} loss {} accu {}'.format(eidx +1 , bidx +1, train_loss, train_acc))
            epoch_acc.append(train_acc)
            epoch_loss.append(train_loss)
        print('##################################')
        val_acc, val_loss = sess.run([accuracy, loss],
            feed_dict= {X:x_test_data, Y: y_test_onehot_encoded_array})
        print('epoch {} # test accuracy {} $ test loss {}'.format(eidx +1, val_acc, val_loss ))
        print('##################################') 
        # Let keep epoch level values for plotting
        train_losses.append(np.mean(epoch_loss))
        train_accuracies.append(np.mean(epoch_acc))
        val_losses.append(val_loss)
        val_accuracies.append(val_acc)
```

My output for each epoch:

```
epoch 1679 training batch 100 loss nan accu 0.009999999776482582
epoch 1679 training batch 200 loss nan accu 0.0
epoch 1679 training batch 300 loss nan accu 0.019999999552965164
epoch 1679 training batch 400 loss nan accu 0.0
epoch 1679 training batch 500 loss nan accu 0.009999999776482582
##################################
epoch 1679 # test accuracy 0.009999999776482582 $ test loss nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss is going to `'nan'`, this is happening because your loss function is not robust, i.e. when `Y_pred_prob` is zero it goes to `-inf`.
You can change it like this:

```
#create loss function (cross entropy)
epsilon = 1e-16
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.log(Y_pred_prob + epsilon))
```

That should do it!